# How to save the output of a stored procedure to a log table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that every night will be executed by the windows task schedular. I just need to know the following 3 things about the execution of the stored procedure:
  1. is the stored procedure executed by the task schedular?
  2. Is the stored procedure executed but with errors?
  3. Is the stored procedure executed successfully?

I have created a table which will hold this information. The table has two fields: Datetime and Description.

At the end of my stored procedure I have written an insert statement that inserts a record to my table for every run (see code below). But I need to define two inserts (see items 2 and 3 above), 3(Successfully) or 2(with Errors). Number 1 is when the sp is not executed so there is no record inserted to the table. I have used the following statement but it is not working, because when a error accours before the insert to the table, the stored procedure stops, so the insert never happens.

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and @@ERROR = 0
BEGIN
insert into Table1
select GETDATE(), 'Successfully'
END

ELSE 
insert into Table1
select GETDATE(), 'With errors'
```

Do you know a good way to solve this problem? Which statements can I use to save a record the this table?

I am using SQL server 2005.

P.S. This data will be displayed in a report: I will write a query which has to return al the data from the table + the dates which are not existed in the table between a from and to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your procedure should have a `TRY/CATCH` implementation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976(v=sql.90).aspx

Wrap the whole procedure logic inside `BEGIN TRY ... END TRY` and use your `CATCH` block to  write errors in the log table. Successful logs are written from the end of `TRY` block.

You can also combine with [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178592%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) if you need to handle any custom error checking and 'jump' from anywhere inside procedure to the `CATCH` block.

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ba46/1)**

Comment: when a error occurs in the Try block then the stored procedure will not go further to the catch block, am i right? I am talking here about insert fails like duplicate key errors etc..

Comment: You are not right. If error occurs in the Try block - the stored procedure WILL go to the catch block (unless a severe system error occurs). That is exactly why it exists.
Here is a demo - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ba46/1

Comment: I tested it in the query window, not as a stored procedure. I think that testing it as a query was the problem.  Can you tell what kind of errors can be handled by the try catch block? What can I understand under system errors?

Comment: Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms164086(v=sql.90).aspx There are 25 levels of severity errors. Levels 0-10 are just warnings and will not stop the execution of SP. Levels 11-19 will jump to your catch block. Levels 20-25 will break connection. Most of the errors you'll be interested in are levels 11-16

Answer (score 0):

You can use the administrative task scheduler to execute stored procedures at a specific time. You must first define a task for the stored procedure execution. Then, when the specified time or event occurs for the stored procedure to run, the administrative task scheduler calls the stored procedure.

Specifically, the administrative task scheduler performs the following actions:

The administrative task scheduler connects to the DB2® member that is specified in the task parameter DB2SSID. If the administrative task scheduler cannot establish a connection, it skips execution of the stored procedure and sets the last execution status to the NOTRUN state.
The administrative task scheduler retrieves parameter values for the stored procedure from DB2 by using the SELECT statement that is defined in the task parameter procedure-input. If an error occurs when the administrative task scheduler retrieves those parameter values, the administrative task scheduler:
Does not call the stored procedure.
Sets the last execution status of the task to the error code that is returned by DB2.
The administrative task scheduler issues an SQL CALL statement with the retrieved parameter values and a stored procedure name. The procedure name is concatenated from the task parameters procedure-schema and procedure-name. The SQL CALL statement is synchronous, and the execution thread is blocked until the stored procedure finishes execution. The administrative task scheduler sets the last execution status to the values that are returned by DB2.
The administrative task scheduler issues a COMMIT statement.
The administrative task scheduler closes the connection to DB2.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I can't use another approach than I have described because of the users that will have this report.